# How to display xml file in a web browser?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I created a normal xml file using this control in c#:

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("XMLFile.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

& the file was created correctly and it has the specific tags & everything. [ I followed this [tutorial]](http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/how-to-create-xml.htm)

But I want the file to be sent online so thet it can be used by other services ....

So, I tried this :

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(Response.OutputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

But this outputs a weird file on the browser that doesn't have any kind of tags ... so how can I make the file stream as a normal xml file ?

Comment: Try different browser. As far as I know Firefox and Chrome sometimes hide tags even if the XML file is correct.

Comment: Maybe setting Response.ContentType = "text/xml"...

Comment: Before you instantiate the XmlTextWriter

Comment: When I do this, this error shows in the browser: XML Parsing Error: junk after document element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(Response.OutputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer.Indentation = 2;

```
    writer.WriteStartElement("table");
    createNode("1","Product 1","1000",writer);
    createNode("2", "Product 2", "2000", writer);
    createNode("3", "Product 3", "3000", writer);
    createNode("4", "Product 4", "4000", writer);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
    writer.Close();
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Response.End();                            --------did you remember that part?
```

[reference](http://www.dotnetperls.com/outputstream)